# How to send runtime (WAR) to remote MobileFirst 7.1 Development Server?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

Using CLI runtime is not pushed to remote development server (only adapters and applications). Is there a way to push runtime (WAR) to remote development server?

Answer (score 0):

The CLI is not supposed to deploy the .war file. The CLI only handles the project artifacts.

If you want to "share" a war file with another remote server then you could simply copy over the entire project folder to a different machine and launch it there. Then, in your original machine, add the remote server using "mfp server add".

Since the two projects are essentially the same, pushing wlapps and adapters should then pass successfully.